# GUI for database tables with pygtk and glade

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, glade

I'm building a database front-end with python and glade. I need to present SQL query results in the form of database tables inside my app's window (schema followed by tuples/records). Both the schema and the database entries are dynamic because the schema could be that of a join operation or in general altered and the number of tuples could be any valid number.One possible solution could be to format a given table with python, create a text object in my GUI and change its' value to that produced by python. Advices and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: libgda has pre-built widgets for this. I don't know enough about it to know if they're what you want.

Comment: That's a very nice library. Unfortunately I can't intergrate it to my project. Next time I'll use it for sure though.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the number and name of the columns to display isn't known beforehand, you could just create a `gtk.TreeView` widget in glade and modify it as you need in the application code.

This widget could be updated to use a new model using `gtk.TreeView.set_model` and the columns could be adapted to match the information to be dsplayed with the `gtk.TreeView.{append,remove,insert}_column` columns.

Regarding the model, you coud create a new `gtk.ListStore` with appropriate columns depending on the results from the database.

I hope this helps.